# how to set such that a button click displays a form widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a flutter beginning and is still learning by tutorials and coding. I kind of made a gmap app in flutter. It shows a map, you can place a marker which will display a widget with some info. This widget has a button which supposedly should show a form widget that I can populate and edit. But the problem is clicking the button doesn't show the form widget. I want it to be shown immediately when I click the button for each marker I placed.

the code: home page

```
Widget? _pillInfoWindow;
Widget? _saveForm;
        
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_pillInfoWindow = null; // Initialize it to null
_saveForm = null;
}
... scaffold ...
             
body: SingleChildScrollView(
           child: Column(
              children: [
                 Stack(
                   children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: screenheight,
                        width: screenwidth,
                        child: GoogleMap(
                          initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                           ...
                           onTap: _handleTap,
                           mapType: _defaultMapType,
                           onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                             _controller.complete(controller);
                        },
                       ),
                    ),
                        if (_pillInfoWindow != null) _pillInfoWindow!,
                        if (_saveForm != null) _saveForm!,
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              floatingActionButton: _getFloatingActionButton(),
            );
          }

  Future<void> addMarker(
      LatLng mLatLng, String mTitle, String mDescription) async {
    final Uint8List markerIcon =
        await getBytesFromAsset('assets/images/icons/pin.png', 100);
    setState(() {
      _markers.clear();
      _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId:
            MarkerId((mTitle + "_" + _markers.length.toString()).toString()),
        position: mLatLng,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: mTitle,
          snippet: mDescription,
        ),

        icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(
            markerIcon), //BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      ));

      _pillInfoWindow = getPillInfowindow(mLatLng, mTitle, mDescription);
    });
    final MarkerId markerId =
        MarkerId((mTitle + "_" + _markers.length.toString()).toString());
  }

  Future<void> _handleTap(LatLng tappedPoint) async {
    print(tappedPoint);
    final words = ...
    print(words.data()!.words);
    LatLng mLatLng = tappedPoint;
    String mTitle = ...
    String mDescription =...

    setState(() {
      _markers.clear();
      if (words.isSuccessful()) {
        addMarker(mLatLng, mTitle, mDescription);
        _pillInfoWindow = getPillInfowindow(mLatLng, mTitle, mDescription);
      } else {
        print(words.error());
      }
    });
  }
```

THE WIDGET DISPAYED WHEN PLACING MARKER

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mymapp/screens/home_page.dart';
import 'package:mymapp/widgets/get_save_form.dart';

Widget? _saveForm;
Widget getPillInfowindow(mLatLng, mTitle, mDescription) {
  return Positioned(
    bottom: 100, right: 0, left: 0,
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
              BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 20,
                  offset: Offset.zero,
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5))
            ]),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                child: ClipOval(
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/pin2.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover))),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('title:${mTitle}', //${mTitle}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors
                                .green)), //currentlySelectedPin.labelColor)),
                    Text(
                        'Desc: ${mDescription}', // ${currentlySelectedPin.location.longitude.toString()}',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey)),
                  ], // end of Column Widgets
                ), // end of Column
              ),
            ), // second widget
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: IconButton(
                   onPressed: () {
                    _saveForm = getSaveForm();
                  },
                  icon: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/icons/save.png',
                  ),
                  iconSize: 40,
                ) 
                )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ); // end of Container
}
```

THIS WIDGET IS IN ANOTHER DART FILE AND HAS AN ICONBUTTON, CLICKING IT SHOULD DISLAY A FORMWIDGET WHICH IS IN ANOTHER DARTFILE

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mymapp/screens/home_page.dart';

Widget getSaveForm() {
  print('button clicked');

  return Positioned(
    top: 100,
    right: 10,
    left: 10,
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        height: 250,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
              BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 20,
                  offset: Offset.zero,
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5))
            ]),
        child: Form(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                hintText: 'Enter your name',
                labelText: 'Name',
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                hintText: 'Enter your name',
                labelText: 'Name',
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 40.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Submit'),
                  onPressed: null,
                )),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

but the formwidget doesnt even get displayed when I click iconbutton. but the print statement get displayed each time so it does work. I don't know what's wrong here.

edit; its not even shown in widget tree. How to get it displayed?
[image: widget tree. animatedPositined is pillinfowindow]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding one more `setState()` as follows :

```
Future<void> _handleTap(LatLng tappedPoint) async {
    ...
    ...
    setState(() {
      _markers.clear();
      if (words.isSuccessful()) {
        addMarker(mLatLng, mTitle, mDescription);
        _pillInfoWindow = getPillInfowindow(mLatLng, mTitle, mDescription);
      } else {
        print(words.error());
      }
    });

    /// This is the code addition.
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((e) => setState(() {}));
    ...
    ...
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't work bro. The form widget doesn't even gets displayed. Can you help me out with this pls?